# Method "from" not recognize in a Jpa Model object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have written a service which makes a query using as filters several fields. I want to learn to use the "Example" class of JPA. The problem is that the DatiAccessoriFascicoloModel.from method is not recognized by Eclipse.

The class DatiAccessoriFascicoloModel actually does not contain a "from" method, but I followed this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example which suggests the use of a construct similar to Model.from in order to build the Example object.

```
public DatiAccessoriFascicoloModel findByIdFascAndIdRegistr(long idFascicolo, long idRegistro){
    DatiAccessoriFascicoloModel datiAccessFascic = new DatiAccessoriFascicoloModel();
    Example<DatiAccessoriFascicoloModel> example = Example.of(DatiAccessoriFascicoloModel.from(null,idFascicolo,idRegistro,null,null));
    Optional<DatiAccessoriFascicoloModel> actual = datiAccessoriFascicoloRepository.findOne(example);
    
    if(actual.isPresent()) {
        return actual.get();
    }
    else return null;
    return null;
}
```

I made efforts to search guides in order to find a solution. I want to understand where the problem is, my suspicion is that there is a confusion in the classes used or imported.

Comment: I think this is one of the details left out of the tutorial, and that the author created a `static` method called `from` to take the place of a constructor, and that is one of the details they glossed over using the comment _"// constructor, getters etc."_ in the `Passengers` class. There is nothing in Java nor in JPA that would somehow automatically create a method called `from`.

Comment: This is confirmed if you look at the GitHub repository linked at the end of the tutorial. Specifically, look at [`Passenger.from`](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-jpa-query/src/main/java/com/baeldung/boot/passenger/Passenger.java#L36). In other words, your question is based on a misconception.